# Sending the data from a axios.get request in a discord bot message

Tags: discord.js

I have a discord bot that gets info from an API. The current issue I'm having is actually getting the information to be sent when the command is run.

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios.get('https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=asean.my.to')
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
});



module.exports = {
    name: 'serverstatus',
    description: 'USes an API to grab server status ',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send();
    },
};
```

Comment: Don't you think fetching the data should happen inside your `execute` method?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got this code from Legend few seconds ago.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'serverstatus',
    description: 'USes an API to grab server status ',
    execute(message, args) {
        axios.get('https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=asean.my.to')
        .then(response => {
          message.channel.send(JSON.stringify(response.data, 0, 4));
        });  
    },
};
```

Comment: We both got the code from legend lmao. Advice use code format

Answer (score -2):

Just sayint heres the fixe

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'serverstatus',
    description: 'USes an API to grab server status ',
    execute(message, args) {
        axios.get('https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=asean.my.to')
        .then(response => {
          message.channel.send(JSON.stringify(response.data, 0, 4));
        });  
    },
};
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is not a typical forum. By accepting [iOnly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767563/8289918), you have already indicated that that solution solved your problem. Please do not post a new answer with the same solution as another answer. Have a look at the [tour].